# Python SQLite3 sum of daily sales into months

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, datetime

I know this question is answered elsewhere but the SQL answers seem too over-complicated for me, a beginner.

Database file:

```
Cold Drink,     SalesInDay
01/01/2019      195
02/01/2019      179
01/02/2019      185
02/02/2019      190
```

The formatting is not good but here is a sample. There is a column for day dates in the year and another column for total sales on that day. I have not included all dates and months for simplicity.

How would I get the sum of total sales for each month and week? such as... January total sales, January week 1 sales, for each month

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (When it comes to date/time, many products are far from ANSI SQL compliant.)

Comment: DB browser for SQLITE3